# conditional CSS based upon div not screen

Tags: css, conditional-statements

So I have done some research and am close to an answer, but what I am trying to do may not be possible with CSS alone which I really hope it is.

The end goal is to set the width of the elements with a class of bricks to 90% if the width of the element with the id of primary is 915 or less.

html snippet:

```
<div id='primary'>
    <div class='bricks'>
        <p>div-1</p>
    </div>
    <div class='bricks'>
        <p>div-2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css snippet:

```
#primary{
    width:100%;
}

.bricks{
    width:45%;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 915px ){
    .bricks{
        width:90%;
    }
}
```

This currently works and sets the width of the elements with bricks as a class to 90% if the screen size is less than 915px. However the catch is that there is dynamic content that may or may not be floated to the left and right of the element with the id of primary. This means that the screen size does not always determine the width of the element.

Question: Is there a way to set conditional CSS for `.bricks` using only CSS (no javascript/php/etc.) based upon the width of `#primary` not the size of the screen?

I know that this could easily be done with javascript, but for it to work with other javascript/jQuery plugins, the css has to be set in the CSS stylesheet not in the element style attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no way to put a if condition on a div width**.

***`I know that this could easily be done with javascript, but for it to work with other javascript/jQuery plugins, the css has to be set in the CSS stylesheet not in the element style attribute.`***

For this you can use 2 different classes in your stylesheet i.e.

```
.wide {width:90%;}
.half {width:45%;}
```

Now you can check with jQuery the `#primary` container width and set the class:

```
const $primary = $("#primary");
$primary
    .find(".bricks")
        .addClass($primary.width() < 915 ? "wide" : "half")
```

Comment: that sounds plausible, let me try this and see where I get. I think you might have a brilliant answer here!

Comment: this code has been put into action and works wonderfully. Thanks @Champ for helping me think outside of the box. You can view it in action at http://amasterdesigns.com Bear with me as I am still getting the templates all set how I like them and the masonry is a little buggy sometimes still searching for the why, I believe it to be padding/margin/gutter issues